# delete ibooks and podcast app from ipad air2

Tags: ipad

I am trying to free up space and want to delete the podcast and ibooks apps.  I went into settings-restrictions and lifted restrictions for these apps but still can't delete them. How is it possible to delete these apps?

Answer (score 1):

No, the stock/standard Apple apps can't be deleted.  You can delete individual podcasts or iBooks, but not the apps themselves.  Hopefully, Apple will allow this in a future iOS release.

Comment: However the apps don't each take up much space so deleting 2 apps won't help much - deleting any podcasts would do more and you can do that from in the app